How to change height and width of Apache Echart canvas?
I am using Apache E-Chart to do visualizations.
This is my option for the gauge graph
  const option = {
    backgroundColor: '#eee111',
    grid: {
      height: "100px",
      width: "100px"
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c}%'
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Pressure',
        type: 'gauge',
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        progress: {
          show: true
        },
        detail: {
          valueAnimation: true,
          formatter: '{value}'
        },
        data: [
          {
            value: 50,
            name: 'SCORE'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

As you can see, the #eee111 colour correspond to the canvas of the gauge chart.
However, I cannot find anyways that I can increase / decrease the size of said canvas, and it is always stuck in this size.

Hence, I would like to ask how can I manually adjust the size of the background (I want the yellow colour canvas to change in size)? Thanks.

Does this answer your question?
